# jQuery validation engine - How to safely re-validate form with changed class attribute on inputs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm making some tests with validation engine, and I find the messages are rendering wrong (at the corner on the page), so... is it possible to properly render the messages when you dynamically change the class attributes with jQuery? like a re-validation of the form? (with the class attributes of the input changed)

**UPDATE:** I tried to use the `'validate'` action, but it's the same thing. I'm using 3 tables here with 4 checkboxes each. So, on a dropdownlist change, I switch tables (when selecting an option, one table appears (remove `disabled` from inputs and `display:none`) and the other 2 dissapears (put `disabled` to inputs and putting `display:none` to table). The checkboxes names render with a Thymeleaf preprocessing expression, so I thought that maybe that was. I created an alternate version of the minCheckbox that uses alt attribute instead of name, but to no avail. Works well, but the error persists. The action of making tables appear and dissapear is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it yet.

**UPDATE #2:** Ok, I have this click event for the save button first:

```
    $('input[name="input_save"]').click(function() {
        if(flag == false){
             $("#frmUsuarioCrear").validationEngine();
             flag = true;
         }

        if(flag2 == true)
        {
            $("#frmUsuarioCrear").validationEngine('attach');
            flag2 = false;
        }
    });

    $("#frmUsuarioCrear").bind("jqv.form.result", function(event, errorFound) {
            if(errorFound)
                alert("Hay algunos problemas con sus datos. Revise y vuelva a intentar.");
    });
```

I also put the bind for the form. That flag is for the engine to be reactivated only when is detached. So, in the change event of the dropdownlist:

```
    $('#ddlModulo').change(function(){
        var val = this.value;

        if(val == "ADQUIRIENTE")
        {
            $('#modulo_1').find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_1').removeAttr("style");    
            $('#modulo_2').css("display", "none");
            $('#modulo_3').css("display", "none");
            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $('#modulo_1').find("input:first").attr("class", "validate[funcCall[checkHooks]]");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
        }
        else if(val == "COMERCIO")
        {
            $('#modulo_1').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_1').css("display", "none");
            $('#modulo_2').removeAttr("style");    
            $('#modulo_3').css("display", "none");

            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").show();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").find("select").removeAttr("disabled");

            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $('#modulo_1').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input:first").attr("class", "validate[funcCall[checkHooks]]");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
        }
        else if(val == "EMISOR")
        {
            $('#modulo_1').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#modulo_1').css("display", "none");
            $('#modulo_2').css("display", "none");  
            $('#modulo_3').removeAttr("style");     

            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").show();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").find("select").removeAttr("disabled");

            $('#modulo_1').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input:first").attr("class", "validate[funcCall[checkHooks]]");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#modulo_1').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#modulo_1').css("display", "none");
            $('#modulo_2').css("display", "none");
            $('#modulo_3').css("display", "none");

            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(6)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").hide();
            $("#main tr:nth-child(7)").find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 

            $('#modulo_1').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_2').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
            $('#modulo_3').find("input:first").removeAttr("class");
        }

        if(flag == true){
            $("#frmUsuarioCrear").validationEngine('detach');
            flag2 = true;
        }            

    });
```

I did this but the prompt doesn't render where it should. BTW, I add the class for validation on each first input of the right table when selecting the option of the dropdown. This ensures that the prompt only appears in the first checkbox only. (I'm using a function that as the change event upon a selected option gets from its corresponding table all the checkboxes and sees if there's some checked, if not returns an alert. In other words, a funcCall for the validation engine.

```
function checkHooks(field, rules, i, options)
{

    var val = $('#ddlModulo').val();

        if(val == "ADQUIRIENTE")
        {
            var inputs =  $('#modulo_1').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

            if(inputs.length == 0){
                return options.allrules.checkHooks.alertText;
            }
        }
        else if(val == "COMERCIO")
        {
            var inputs =  $('#modulo_2').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

            if(inputs.length == 0){
                return options.allrules.checkHooks.alertText;
            }
        }
        else if(val == "EMISOR")
        {
            var inputs =  $('#modulo_3').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

            if(inputs.length == 0){
                return options.allrules.checkHooks.alertText;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE #3:** I changed this code a bit. I added a second conditional in the submit click event, that checks a second flag. If it's true, it will attach the validation engine. And it will be false. On the dropdownlist change event, I set a similar condition based on the first flag, just that it detach the engine when changed and turns the second flag to true (so it will enter the condition on submit, and re-attach the engine)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$("#Form-ID").validationEngine('validate');
```

Comment: Already tried. Didn't work. I think it is related with the rendering of the prompt itself. I put more about it on the update.

Comment: Try re-attaching the engine to the form in your change, after enabling/showing the other fields. Because when the engine is initialized, it builds the array of elements inside the form to validate.

Comment: I tried this but with no avail. Just in case, I put the code for the click event of the submit button, the change event of the dropdown, and the function I use for the funcCall validator.

Comment: You are detaching the engine in your `$('#ddlModulo').change()` and never re attaching it before the submit is clicked. Also, the attach code should be `$("#frmUsuarioCrear").validationEngine('attach');`

Comment: Ok, I did it like you said (read update #3). But apparently the same happens anyway. You said that it builds the array when the engine is initialize, but attach and initialize are two separate actions. Are you sure that detaching and the attaching works this way? =S